# Can I run iPhone apps on iPad Mini 3 using iPhone 6 compatibility?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have to get a device to test my apps on 64bit processors, and I am interested in iPad Mini 3. However, I would like to know, if I can run apps using iPhone compatibility to see how they would work on iPhone 6 [ and iPhone 6 plus if that's possible].

Is there any way I could do it? I can't find any info about this matter, and both iPad Mini 3 and iPhone 6 share the same ppi, so the experience should be simular [accept for the fact you hold the device differently].

I cannot do the same using simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Nope iPads can't run as iPhones. An iPhone app on iPad will run with compatibility mode (which is has not exactly the same behaviour as an iPhone). You'll have to test it either with a real iPhone or with the simulator.

Comment: you kind of contradict yourself. You say Nope and then you say it will run with compatibility mode, which is exactly what I want to have. My question is, whether the compatibility mode will work with iphone6 resolution?

Comment: By compatibility mode I mean it will run but you'll not see the same behaviour as on an iPhone 6.

Comment: What behaviour do you mean? I won't be able to use phone calls nor GPS on some models, that's understandable, but is there anything else? I've got iPad 3rd gen and it runs all of the apps ok, however the display ratio is of iPhone 4

Comment: You'll get the same behaviour with the iPad mini as on your iPad.

Comment: Just to clarify, newest ipad still use the iPhone 4 display ratio in compatibility mode?

Comment: Yes the iPad screen size did not change.

Comment: but iPhone screen size did.